# How to resolve error "String not recognized as valid DateTime"?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have three date type variables passed from a batch file as strings. When they come over to the PS script, they are seen as:

- 20190710 112538
- 20190710 112538
- 20190710

The problem I am facing is that when I attempt to parse them, I receive an error stating that the string is not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have tried changing the culture to and invariant one and no difference. I am sure I am missing something. Could I get some help with parsing these strings successfully?

Values Sent from here:

```
set YYYY=%DATE:~-4%
set MM=%DATE:~4,2%
set DD=%DATE:~7,2%
set HH=%time:~0,2%
set NN=%time:~3,2%
set SS=%time:~6,2%
set MS=%time:~9,2%
SET "_oStart=%YYYY%%MM%%DD% %HH%%NN%%SS%%MS%" 

SET "_PSScript=C:\xx\xx.ps1"
SET "_oEnd=%YYYY%%MM%%DD% %HH%%NN%%SS%%MS%" 
SET "_oDateRan=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"
SET "_PSCMD=Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%_PSScript%" -oStart "%_oStart%" -oEnd "%_oEnd%" -oDateRan "%_oDateRan%"
```

```bsh
Param(
    [String]$oStart,
    [String]$oEnd,
    [String]$oDateRan
)

[DateTime]$DateRan = [DateTime]::ParseExact($oDateRan, "yyyyMMdd", $null)
[DateTime]$StartTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($oStart, "yyyyMMdd HHmmssff", $null)
[DateTime]$End = [DateTime]::ParseExact($oEnd, "yyyyMMdd HHmmssff", $null)
```

Error Message:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not
recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Comment: The string "20190710 112538" matches neither the pattern `yyyyMMdd` nor the pattern `yyyyMMdd HHmmssff`. Also, you should use `[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` instead of `$null`. For further help please show how you're invoking the code snippet you posted as well as the full error message.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this was updated.

Comment: Your batch code does not define the variables `%YYYY%`, `%MM%` and `%DD%`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers my apologies. I made that update.

Comment: Check the values you're passing to the PowerShell script. Make sure they are what you expect them to be. Because the format of `%DATE%` might not. Most likely you need to change `set MM=%DATE:~4,2%` to `set MM=%DATE:~3,2%` and `set DD=%DATE:~7,2%` to `set DD=%DATE:~6,2%`.